# Avoiding relative paths in sourcemaps that depend on other packages in a monorepo

Tags: webpack, source-maps, aws-amplify, lerna, monorepo

When building packages in a monorepo using [Lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna), how should webpack be configured to ensure that intra-monorepro, cross-package dependencies will emit sourcemaps that point to the installed location (e.g. `./node_modules/@foo/bar/lib/foobar.js`) and *don't* point to a relative path to the local folder where the package was built (e.g. `../bar/lib/foobar.js`)? The latter folder won't exist at runtime, which breaks debugging in Chrome or VSCode.

Background: I use the [`amplify-js`](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js) library. Its sourcemaps are broken which makes debugging painful. I want to build a PR to fix this library's sourcemaps, but I'm not sure what changes are needed.

The problem is that source maps generated for intra-monorepo dependencies contain relative paths to the location at build time, e.g. `webpack:///../core/lib/index.js`. But when installing `amplify-js` from npm, only the root package is installed directly under `node_modules` at `node_modules/amplify-js`. Other dependent packages in the monorepo, e.g. the `core` package, are installed under `@aws-amplify`, e.g. `/node_modules/@aws-amplify/core`.  This makes the `webpack:///../core/lib/index.js` path in the sourcemap fail at runtime because `../core` doesn't exist.

Here's an excerpt from a sourcemap with the problem (
https://unpkg.com/aws-amplify@1.1.22/dist/aws-amplify.js.map). I formatted it for clarity:

```
{
  "version":3,
  "sources:[
    "webpack:///webpack/universalModuleDefinition",
    "webpack:///aws-amplify.js",
    "webpack:///webpack/bootstrap 02623d179e36bcc68243",
    "webpack:////root/app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/core.js",
    "webpack:///../core/lib/index.js",  // PROBLEM!!!!
    "webpack:////root/app/node_modules/graphql/module/error/index.js",
```

How should webpack (or Lerna? or something else?) be configured to ensure that sourcemaps for intra-monorepo dependencies always point to the node_modules folder where those dependencies will be installed at runtime?

Using the excerpt above, here'd what I'd expect to see:

```
{
  "version":3,
  "sources:[
    "webpack:///webpack/universalModuleDefinition",
    "webpack:///aws-amplify.js",
    "webpack:///webpack/bootstrap 02623d179e36bcc68243",
    "webpack:////root/app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/core.js",
    "webpack:////root/app/node_modules/@aws-amplify/core/lib/index.js",  // OK
    "webpack:////root/app/node_modules/graphql/module/error/index.js",
```

If you want to repro the problem:

- git clone https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js.git
- cd amplify-js
- yarn
- yarn bootstrap
- yarn build  *(warning, this takes a few minutes)*
- open `./packages/aws-amplify/dist/aws-amplify.js.map`

Expected: no relative paths to other packages

Actual: relative paths like `"webpack:///../core/lib/index.js"`

Comment: any chance you were able to solve this? running into a similar problem which prevents debugging

Comment: I "solved" it by forking these packages and changing the sourcemap paths that were generated. Also ended up doing a lot of custom work in my bundler config. Huge PITA. It's been a few years so can't remember the details, though.

I also PR-ed some changes back into aws-amplify to try to make things easier for the next person.